# Primary key in realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I create a default realm file to use it during first launching app as replacement (I want to have a file with initial data). I start with creating default realm file from csv files. The problem is that I am not sure if my structure is correct. When I import data from csv (in Realm Browser) and try to import next data for next class, I get this error

[image]

I have main class called Exercises

```
class Exercises: Object {
    @Persisted var id: Int = 0
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var category: Category?
    @Persisted var equipment: Equipment?
    @Persisted var instruction: String
    @Persisted var muscle: List<Muscle>
    @Persisted var gif: String?
    @Persisted var image: String?
    
    convenience init(id: Int, name: String, category: Category?, equipment: Equipment?, instruction: String, muscle: [Muscle], gif: String?, image: String?) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.equipment = equipment
        self.instruction = instruction
        self.muscle.append(objectsIn: muscle)
        self.gif = gif
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

and other classes for separate things

```
class Equipment: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var equipmentID = 0
    @Persisted var equipment: String = ""
    
    convenience init(equipment: String) {
        self.init()
        self.equipment = equipment
    }
}

class Category: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var categoryID = 0
    @Persisted var category: String = ""
    
    convenience init(category: String) {
        self.init()
        self.category = category
    }
  
}

class Muscle: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var muscleID = 0
    @Persisted var muscle: String = ""
    
    convenience init(muscle: String) {
        self.init()
        self.muscle = muscle
    }
}
```

Finally I want to receive structure like below. I wonder if it is correct way? Maybe better option is just set text in fields instead of reference to class (after all realm is non-relational)?

[image]

Comment: A question; do you want Exercises Object to have a primary key? `@Persisted var id: Int = 0`? Second thing is the error you're getting when importing data references the Category class. It sounds like the flat file your importing has duplicate primary key of `1` and primary keys must be unique. I would inspect that file. Please keep questions to one per but the screenshot you've included doesn't directly correlate to the objects (code) in the question per se. In other words we don't know what that screen shot represents, another object? Oh, Realm has relational capability (is relational)

Comment: I want all realm classes to have primary key (primary key for main class called Exercises and others like equipment, category, and muscles), because it make searching easier. Is it correct?

Comment: No, it does not make searching easier per se - filtering is filtering. However, objects with primary keys are easier to work with and are more efficient; you can directly update a specific object or read in a specific object by it's primary key *without having to filter*. So... you will need to update your Exercises model to add a primary key and then back to your issue. Primary keys must be unique so the likely cause of your issue is you've got two Category objects being assigned a primary key of "1".